# implicitly convert string to string_view

Tags: c++, string, implicit-conversion, string-view

```
void Foo1(string_view view) {
... 
}

string str = "one two three";

Foo1("one two three"); // Implicitly convert char* to string_view

Foo1(str);
```

[image]
I wonder which constructor converts char* to string_view implicitly and which one converts the string to string_view implicitly?

I know constructor (4) convert const char* to string_view but what I passed is char*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::string_view` has a non-`explicit` [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) taking `const char*`, which supports implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string_view`.

> `constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s);`

When you say:

> but what I passed is `char*`.

You're actually passing a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) (i.e. `"one two three"`), whose type is `const char[14]` (including the null terminator `'\0'`), which could decay to `const char*`.

And `std::string` has a non-`explicit` [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view) which supports implicit conversion from `std::string` to `std::string_view`.

> `constexpr operator std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>() const noexcept;`

Comment: What makes the ```conversion operator``` special so that string to string_view is implicit?
I notice basic_string also has ```c_str()``` function but that does not make string to char* implicit?

Comment: @echoLee `std::string` defines a conversion operator to `std::string_view`, and it is implicit simply by virtue of the fact that it is not declared as `explicit`. `std::string::c_str()` is not a conversion operator, just a plain method. `std::string` does not define any conversion operator to `char*`, neither implicit nor explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_basic_string_view:
[image: basic_string::operator basic_string_view()]

together with string_view's copy constructor (2)